'drop off' use when talking about possible actions
Today, on the radio, I heard:

There will be next meeting on Friday. I don't know if any action will drop off out of this.

I imagine it means that someone expects that there might be questions/actions to take care of after the meeting, but is this sentence correct? Is it used in a real life?

It sounds very non-standard. What radio station or network, and who was speaking? Have you written it exactly, because it has other grammar problems? At a guess, I would think maybe that the meeting may agree to remove one or more actions from a plan or agenda (so that they 'drop off', (like objects falling from a shelf).

There will be next meeting. is not English. Perhaps the speaker was not an English speaker. "drop off" is not right there at all. [fyi, I heard a sentence like this, not such a sentence.0]

As a native BrE speaker I've never heard this phrasing used, so I suggest that it is not normal in everyday speech.
As to the meaning, I think you are correct. A more normal way of saying it would be

I don't know if any action will arise from this.

or

I don't know if this will result in any action.

=== later ===
Based on various comments the sentence could be ambiguous. My answer is based on a third possible wording

I don't know if any action will come out of this.

Which, IMHO, is an inferior way of saying one of my first two possibilities, but I concede it could mean

I don't know if any action will be dropped from the agenda before this meeting. [for unspecified reasons]

But as others have said, both sentences are poor English. The first sentence could be either "The next meeting will be on Friday" or "The meeting will be on next Friday"

Even the word "out" from the original would be preserved in the idiom "I don't know if any action will come out of this"

The whole phrase is garbled English, but I feel this covers pretty much all the bases, although drop off could also mean it's decided that an action(or activity) will cease, which is very similar to the dropping off the agenda.


There will be next meeting on Friday. I don't know if any action will drop off out of this.

Both sentences aren’t good although they can be understood from context.
The next meeting will be on Friday.
Drop off out of this tells us the speaker is talking about whether certain matters could be resolved before the next meeting and hence removed from the agenda.

I don't know how you can be so clear about the meaning, without any further context. It's possible it means "drop off" in the sense of "come to fruition".
